# memcpy hangs when dest is NULL

Tags: crash, memcpy, freeze

I found a problem when memcpy's first argument is 0x0, the expected behaviour crash with SIGSEGV, but it didn't crash, it just hanged there, never return.What could be the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy) behaviour is undefined:

> The behavior is undefined if either dest or src is a null pointer.